# Sending key-strokes to subprocess which runs aplay using fwrite(), pipe() and execlp()

Tags: c++, c, linux, alsa

I want to play arbitrary sounds programatically using `aplay` on linux. Besides playing I want to use the interactive mode to pause the playback which can be achived by pressing space key when running `aplay` from a terminal. I thougth this can be achived by sending `' '` througth the pipe to the process which runs aplay. The playback works but pausing does not.

How do I send the `' '` properly through the pipe? Do I need to do something else ?

here is my code

```
#ifndef APLAY_WRAPPER_H
#define APLAY_WRAPPER_H

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

class APlayWrapper
{
private:
  pid_t m_pid;
  int pipefd[2];  // [0] is for reading and [1] is for writing
  FILE* m_sub_process_input;

public:
  APlayWrapper() : m_pid(0){};

  ~APlayWrapper(){};

  void play(const std::string& pathToFile)
  {
    pipe(pipefd);    // create a pipe
    m_pid = fork();  // spawn a child process
    if (m_pid == 0)
    {
      execlp("/usr/bin/aplay", "/usr/bin/aplay", "-i", pathToFile, (char*)NULL);
    }

    m_sub_process_input = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w");
  };

  void stopPlayback()
  {
    if (isPlaying())
    {
      kill(m_pid, SIGTERM);
    }
  };

  void pauseResumePlayback()
  {
    fwrite(" ", sizeof(char), 1, m_sub_process_input);
  };

  bool isPlaying()
  {
    if (0 == kill(m_pid, 0))
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

#endif
```

Comment: You probably need to set the `m_sub_process_input` stream to unbuffered mode. But using a stream seems like overkill. You could just use the lower level POSIX `write()` on the file descriptor. Also, in the child, you need to `dup2()` the read end of the pipe to the standard input file descriptor before the `exec`.

Comment: You cannot send "keystrokes" through a pipe. A pipe is for sending data. If you want to interact with a program that uses the terminal for "interactive" things, you should use a pty instead of a pipe. If you're just doing a quick hack, you might be able to get your sample to work by calling `fflush` after `fwrite`, but it will be unreliable as it will depend on how exactly aplay reads from the terminal.

Comment: `aplay` actually reads from `stdin`.